# How Are MATLAB's `cpsd()` and SciPy's `csd()` Related?

Tags: matlab, fft, python, spectrum-estimation

I am trying to determine an estimate of the H1 transfer function between two acceleration signals in Python. To do this, I am calculating Pyx using `scipy.signal.csd()` and dividing it by Pxx calculated using `scipy.signal.welch()`

I have used the same method in MATLAB, calculating Pyx using `cpsd()` and Pxx using `pwelch()` and have successfully reproduced the results of using `tfestimate()` by dividing Pyx / Pxx.

When I compare the two methods, the result using scipy is wildly different and I cannot determine why this is the case. Is `scipy.signal.csd()` different from using `cpsd()` in MATLAB?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Both `scipy.signal.csd()` and MATLAB's `cpsd()` use Welch's method.
But their default parameters are different:

1. Window: On MATLAB is it the Hamming Window. On SciPy it is the Hann Window.
2. Segment: MATLAB segments the signal into 8 non overlapping segments. SciPy uses segment length of 256 samples.
3. Detrending: By default SciPy removes the Mean. MATLAB doesn't.

It seems that by setting each parameter by yourself you should get the same results.

Pay attention that you need to have a look at `pwelch()` vs. `scipy.signal.welch()` as well.

Comment: Awesome! I'll have another play around and see if that fixes things.

Comment: Sorry mate. I think I’ve done it now. Cheers.